# Python Asynchronized django rest endpoint

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, django-rest-framework

I have a problem with building a django rest endpoint. Endpoint's task is to return Counter object of all articles in database. Since there can be a lot of articles in database I would like to create asynchronized functions to save CPU. I checked plenty of tutorials on how to work with async but I am still not sure how to cope with this issue. So far my endpoint looks like this:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
async def stats(request):
    result = await count_words()
    return JsonResponse({"result": result})
```

Count_words function looks like this:

```
async def count_words():
    articles = db.query(Article).all()
    article_counters_list = map(lambda x: Counter(x.article_content.split()), articles)
    result = sum(article_counters_list, Counter())
    return result
```

This is not working as assertion error apears "Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'coroutine'>`"

Can you please advice?

Also I assume it should be somehow done with generetors instead of lists so please give any advice on how to make these list more efficient.

```
articles = db.query(Article).all()
article_counters_list = map(lambda x: Counter(x.article_content.split()), articles)
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-rest-framework does not support async view yet.

There is an issue for that: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/7260#

Comment: Why do you infer that they're using an old version of DRF from the fact that they're using the `api_view` decorator? The current documentation (3.12.4) still documents the `api_view` decorator and there isn't any deprecation warning.

Comment: My bad, I confused `api_view` with `detail_route`. Correcting my answer.